# Jaeger duration measurement

Tags: jaeger

Can't find anywhere in Jaeger docs or GitHub what duration represents as a measurement unit. I guess it's milliseconds. Can anyone confirm?

I've looked over the internet and tried to find what duration in Jaeger represents but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer I know but if you like me came here looking for this answer.

**Duration is stored in microseconds.**

From [Jeager Source code](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/blob/c582d89a033a5d71bb8327a4f5ac1452847cd24b/model/json/model.go#LL64C1-L78C2)

```golang
type Span struct {
        TraceID       TraceID     `json:"traceID"`
        SpanID        SpanID      `json:"spanID"`
        ParentSpanID  SpanID      `json:"parentSpanID,omitempty"` // deprecated
        Flags         uint32      `json:"flags,omitempty"`
        OperationName string      `json:"operationName"`
        References    []Reference `json:"references"`
        StartTime     uint64      `json:"startTime"` // microseconds since Unix epoch
        Duration      uint64      `json:"duration"`  // microseconds
        Tags          []KeyValue  `json:"tags"`
        Logs          []Log       `json:"logs"`
        ProcessID     ProcessID   `json:"processID,omitempty"`
        Process       *Process    `json:"process,omitempty"`
        Warnings      []string    `json:"warnings"`
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Found it as well, but forgot about the question here.